# While trying to run "gradle test jacoco" in gitbash I am getting TestExecutionException, NoClassDefFoundError, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-mvc, build.gradle, jacoco

While trying to run jacoco in my gradle project, I am getting exceptions.
I have added following dependencies:

```
  compile "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.8"
  compile "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.8"
  compile "org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.1"
```

I also tried with different options like `providedCompile`, `testCompile` also.
I am getting this exception, while trying to run "gradle test jacoco" in gitbash.

Exceptions:

> org.gralde.api.tasks: TaskExecutionException: Exception failed for
>   task:'practice-app:jacocoTestReport'
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/jacoco/report/IReportVistor
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jacoco.report.IReportVisitor

I also verified other checks like jacoco jars available in my local gradle repo etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also experienced the similar problem during Jacoco integration in one of  our gradle project. The plugin somehow did not bring the required jars. Then, I tried to add all the dependencies manually
say :-

```
compile "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.8"
compile "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.8"  
compile  "org.ow2.asm:asm-all:0.7.8"
```

etc., but that trick also did not work. Still got classnotfound exception against jacoco jars. Then after a lot hit & trial, I came to know about jacocoClasspath. I did the followings:

1) First changed Jacoco version to

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.8+"
}
```

As got some incompatibility version issue (Don't remember the exact error/exception).

2) Then, added the below code in build.gradle to ensure that required dependencies are present in the jacoco class path.

```
jacocoTestReport.doFirst  {
    configurations.testRuntime.each { jacocoClasspath += files(it); }
}
```

Notes:
1) doFirst will be executed before jacoco task gets executed.

2) I just added whatever present in my runtime to the jacocoClasspath. You may refine the code, to add only the required jars to the jacoco class path.